# importing module using pip

Tags: python, module, pip, baseline, baselineremoval

I want to import a module called BaselineRemoval using pip, however, after installing it, python (version 3.8) is giving error of :
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BaselineRemoval'`
I am not familiar with dealing with these kinds of things, so any help with this?

Comment: please paste the code snippet

Comment: Show us the output of `pip --version`.

Comment: ```pip 21.1.1 from /Users/alex/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)```

Comment: How are you running the code?  Are you typing `python myscript.py` at a command prompt, or are you using an IDE, or some other way?

Comment: i am just running the script using spyder 3.8, i suspect this is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Check you writed everythong right;
pip: `pip install BaselineRemoval`
python: `from BaselineRemoval import BaselineRemoval`
[Here](https://pypi.org/project/BaselineRemoval/) is the documentation for more questions you may have.

Comment: yes this is exactly what i wrote, but still no result

Comment: ``` pip install BaselineRemoval ```                                                        and          ```from BaselineRemoval import BaselineRemoval```

Comment: Try copy pasting from here, may be some typo is causing the error

Comment: still no luck doing this

Comment: try ```pip list``` and search for the package, if it isnt there paste the messages printed while installing. If it says every where requirement already satisfied use ```pip uninstall BaselineRemoval``` and try installation again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232194/discussion-between-sagitario-and-alex).